# Kitchen converge takes local changes directly to the instance, not from the chef server

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, chef-infra, devops, cookbook

I made a changes to default.rb recipes file, but not uploaded to chef server. but when I run kitchen converge, chef running local made changes on instance. Clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Kitchen used to test the instance to work as expected, when run kitchen converge it takes the cookbooks on the local machine, runs it on Node.